# How to get results from another method into another method using java?

Tags: java

I made a simple grade system for fun. I'm trying to apply the total of grades and add it to an equation in my `getApercent()` method. However, I keep getting errors and don't know what to do.

```
package gradesystem;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gradesystem {      

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Gradesystem gs = new Gradesystem();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      int Acount,Bcount,Ccount,Dcount,Fcount;
     double ap,bp,cp,dp,fp;
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of A's");
      Acount = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of B's");
      Bcount = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of C's");
      Ccount = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of D's");
      Dcount = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of F's");
      Fcount = keyboard.nextInt();          

     int grades;
      ap = getApercent(Acount);
      System.out.println(ap);
      bp = getBpercent(Bcount);
      System.out.println(bp);
      cp = getCpercent(Ccount);
      System.out.println(cp);
      dp = getDpercent(Dcount);
      System.out.println(dp);
      fp = getFpercent(Fcount);
      System.out.println(fp);       
    }

    public static void Totalgrades(int acount, int bcount, int ccount, int dcount, int fcount){

    int totalofgrades = acount + bcount + ccount + dcount + fcount;      
    System.out.print(totalofgrades);            
    }

    public static double getApercent(int a){
        double ap;      
        ap = (a/a * 100) + 0.5; 
        return Math.round(ap);        
    }

    public static double getBpercent(int b){            
        double bp;
        bp = (b/b * 100) + 0.5;
        return Math.round(bp);          
    }

 public static double getCpercent(int c){           
        double cp;
        cp = (c/c * 100) + 0.5;
        return Math.round(cp);          
    }

 public static double getDpercent(int d){           
        double dp;
        dp = (d/d * 100) + 0.5;
        return dp;          
    }

 public static double getFpercent(int f){           
        double fp;
        fp = (f/f * 100) + 0.5;
        return fp;          
    }   
}
```

Comment: `I keep getting errors and don't know what to do` ... neither do we, because you never told us what the errors are.  What is the exact problem?

Comment: Well for one a/a is basic math. The result will be 1. eg. 10/10 = 1

Comment: Inside the Totalgrades , I'm trying to get the total of Acount, Bcount, and etc. Inside my getApercent() method. I'm trying to do this " a/totalgrades() * 100 + 0.5

Comment: You need to call your Totalgrades() method inside your main method and pass the input parameters to this method.

Comment: i suggest you better to learn and follow basic operator precedence table (Java) as well as basic mathematics too.. thanks @user2157247

Comment: All your getXXXPercent methods do exactly the same. You need to remove all but once of them, and rename it `getPercent`. And then fix the method: it needs two arguments, one for the portion and one for the total. You should return the percentage that the portion is of the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of guessing here. But the methods that calculate the percentage seem off.  Again, assuming; but to calculate the percentage of a whole you would use the following formula `percentage = part/whole * 100`

e.g.

we have 9 grades and 3 are A's, 3 are B's, 2 are C's, 1 is D's, and 0 are E's.

Then I'd expect the percentages to be as follows:

```
33% A  // 3 / 9 * 100
33% B  // 3 / 9 * 100
22% C  // 2 / 9 * 100
11% D  // 1 / 9 * 100
0% E   // 0 / 9 * 100
```

One other thing to point out is the the operator `/` with two ints does integer division. So `3 / 9 == 0`.

You could replace all the specific methods with a more generic version.

```
public static double getPercentage(int gradeCount, int totalNumberOfGrades) {
  double percentage = ( gradeCount / (double) totalNumberOfGrades * 100); 
  return Math.round(percentage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!